# angular-bootstrap typeahead using $http

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I try to use angular-bootstrap's typeahead plugin with $http service.At first, I use $http.success() like this:

```
$scope.filterProvinces = function(val){
    return service.provinceList({
         pageSize : 10,
         queryKey : val
     }).success(function(data, status, headers, config){
          return data.data.list;
       }
     ).error(function(data, status, headers, config){
          alert("no result!");
          return ;
     });
}
```

but it didn't work, so I change the code , like this:

```
$scope.filterProvinces = function(val){
    return service.provinceList({
         pageSize : 10,
         queryKey : val
     }).then(function(response){
         return response.data.data.list;
     });
}
```

and it was working, so I was confused. Why then() is ok but success() is not right.

Comment: The typeahead directive can work with a static array / collection or a promise. `success` and `error` are not standard promise methods. See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#deprecation-notice

Answer (score 3):

If you check the AngularJS [source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/3a3db690a16e888aa7371e3b02e2954b9ec2d558/src/ng/http.js#L910), you'll find that `.success()` actually takes a function itself as an argument, which is then invoked, passing in the deconstructed response object, ultimately calling `.then()` to resolve the promise.

Because of the lack of clarity, this was actually deprecated and the documentation for [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) recommends the use of `.then()` instead.

> The $http legacy promise methods success and error have been
>   deprecated. Use the standard then method instead. If
>   $httpProvider.useLegacyPromiseExtensions is set to false then these
>   methods will throw $http/legacy error.

It's worth checking to make sure that this error is not being thrown.